# Compare large local gson against remote gson

Tags: android, hash, compare, gson

When sending a large pojo I want to check for bytes changes and not detail differences in structure. Maybe serialize and hash the pojo in memory but that can fail on an Android device. Any thoughts would be grate. Should a traverse it dom style maybe.

**OUT**

```
outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter( out, "UTF-8");
jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(outputStreamWriter);
jsonWriter.setIndent("  ");
jsonWriter.setIndent("\t"); 
jsonWriter. beginArray();
mygson.toJson( largeTestPojo, LargeTestPojo.class, jsonWriter );
jsonWriter.endArray();
jsonWriter.flush();
```

**IN**

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( in, "UTF-8");
StatsTypeAdapterFactory stats = new StatsTypeAdapterFactory();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(stats).create();
jsonReader = new JsonReader( isr );
jsonReader. beginArray();
largeTestPojo= gson.fromJson( jsonReader, LargeTestPojo.class );
jsonReader.endArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check for bytes changes and not detail differences in structure

I'm not sure what that means.

> Compare large local gson against remote gson

It's not clear to me where the comparison is to occur, whether the complete input and output contents are to be available in the same place or if something like a hash -- as mentioned -- is to be used to represent something on one end or the other.

If the complete input and output structures are available at the point of comparison, then...

I likely wouldn't use the Gson API (or any serialization API) for the task of data structure (or service message) value comparisons.  I prefer to use serialization APIs like Gson only for serialization/deserialization tasks, keeping those layers of the system as thin and as simple as reasonable.

So, I'd probably prefer to deserialize into the target `LargeTestPojo`, and implement a `compareTo` and/or `equals` method for it, or just put the two data sets into a map, and compare from there.